# ECS Scheduled Tasks always 1 task only

Tags: amazon-web-services, task, amazon-ecs

How can I configure my ECS Scheduled task to always be 1 maximum?

So, I'm trying to run a scheduled task, and the tasks will always be 1, but what I dont want if the first task is still running that AWS launches another task, I want it to wait until that task finished and then launch another one, is that possible?

Comment: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/232

Comment: Just saw that, seems like this feature is missing, a workaround would be a lock in S3 or a DB ... The problem with the lock is that my app depends on the scripts to run exactly every 1 minute, Lets say first task runs and takes 60 seconds, the seconds task comes in and stops due to the lock, so now my app will be desynced because the script wont run a entire minute.

Comment: Instead of refusing to run, you could have it wait for the lock to clear. I will say your service architecture sounds a bit fragile.

Comment: Instead of scheduling an ECS task, schedule a lambda function. The function would check or terminate existing task, before starting new one.

Comment: @jordanm Well, it's a game and I need to increment users balance by N every minute. Where N can also be changed by other processes, so not sure how I could design this to avoid using cronjobs. Well, I think I found a way, Queue + Timed messages will do the job I think (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-timers.html)

Comment: not possible currently, I think it can be done using ECS Services, so create a service with a task definition with a desired count of 1 and no autoscale. So it will have only 1 task running always unless that instance is crashed then the ECS will create a new one.